# Can I redirect a remote git repository that has moved from one name or path to a new one using ssh urls?

Tags: ssh, git, symbolic-link

I have an existing, long-lived git repository that I want to move to a different path (and eventually a different server depending on how this works).

Obviously I can make this work by using a symlink from the old location to the new location, but I'd prefer (and will eventually need) a solution that doesn't rely on the previous location being accessible at all, because it's going to go away at some point (which is the whole reason I'm moving it).

The problem is that I already have that repo cloned in countless different places that are accessed only occasionally and is mostly used behind the scenes, like on various VMs and so on, so they're not easy to just update all at once because they would all need to be started and stopped and it would just take a long time and involve a lot of manual effort that I'd like to avoid and a bunch would probably get missed.

So let's say I make my repository available in both places with a symlink:

```
/home/git/git/happy/path
/home/git/git/this/is/a/bad/path -> /home/git/git/happy/path (symlink)
```

On every clone copy, the repository is always cloned from my own local git "hub" server using the ssh:// protocol and I'm hoping to change it like follows:

```
bash# cd /cloned/repo
bash# git config --get remote.origin.url
> ssh://git@my-hub-server/git/this/is/a/bad/path
bash# git pull
> <various git stuff happens here>
bash# git config --get remote.origin.url
> ssh://git@my-hub-server/git/happy/path
```

I am hoping there is some way (hacky solutions are okay) that will work like a HTTP 301 Moved Permanently, but across SSH. The goal would be to cause a single change on the remote "hub" server, that would make all the repositories that pull from there, also update their remote origin url to use the new path. I wonder if there is something I could do with hooks somehow?

If that's totally impossible, I'd be willing to settle for a more reactive solution; for example, I could maybe maybe monitor some logfiles somehow to see whenever that "redirected" symlink repo gets accessed or pulled from, and send me an email alert with the hostname or IP so that I know that I still need to go and update that cloned repo to the new url.

And while we're talking about it, does anyone know whether an https:// repo can be 301 redirected to do what I describe above? Because if git actually supports that feature on https I think that alone would be worth switching my whole repository scheme for.

Comment: It might just *work*. There is a setting called [http.followRedirects](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/en#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpfollowRedirects) and the default is "initial".